# Prove that $\log_5 7$ is irrational

Tags: prime-numbers, logarithms, irrational-numbers

Using contradiction, suppose $\log_5 7$ is rational.
I found $7^q=5^p$ and I have to explain why this is a contradiction.
I don't know how to explain it. This is for homework and my teacher is very detailed about how we explain things.

Comment: It is a contradiction because of [Fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic), prime factorization of a number is unique, you cannot have the same integer being power of one prime and at the same time power of another prime...

Answer (score 2):

*Inspired by [blackpenredpen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MW3kNkM-AUE) :)*

Suppose $\log_5 7$ is rational. Then we may write $\log_5 7 = \frac{a}{b}$, where $a,b$ are positive integers since $\log_5 7 > 0$.

We have $7 = 5^{a/b}$, or $7^b = 5^a$. But one side is always a multiple of $5$ and one side is never a multiple of $5$...